# Making new relic work on a grails app in heroku

Tags: maven, grails, heroku, newrelic, javaagents

I'm having real trouble making new relic work on my grails app in Heroku, This are the things I've tried without success:

1. - Downloaded the java agent
   - Uzip it on the root folder of my app, it creates a folder called new relic
   - Added to the JAVA_OPTS "-javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar"
   - Then heroku can't start, I get "Process exited with status 1" and "State changed from starting to crashed"
2. - Configured the buildConfig.groovy file, set dependencies to: provided 'com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-agent:3.7.0'
   - Set the NEWRELIC_HOME = 'newrelic' folder
   - Set JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -javaagent:target/dependency/newrelic-agent.jar' NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="YOUR APP NAME GOES HERE"
   - Heroku can't start either I get: "Unrecognized VM option 'UseCompressedOops -javaagent:target/dependency/newrelic-agent.jar''"
3. - Tried all this but instead of JAVA_OPTS used GRAILS_OPTS
   - Nothing really happened

The one I supposed should had worked is the second one but in the [heroku site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#java-configuration) there is a part for the maven configuration I don't know how to setup that says: "Customize the build section so it always names the newrelic-agent.jar consistently." maybe there's something there that I'm missing but I wouldn't know what.

So, do you know how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work, the answer was in option one but to change the JAVA_OPTS I needed to use the console.

This sentence worked:

```
heroku config:add JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar'
```

Hope it helps!